# Update MySQL date column

Tags: mysql, database, date, sql-update, mariadb

Let's say I have the following table which has two columns id (int) and date_added (date)

```
-------------------
| id | date_added |
-------------------
| 1  | 2018-02-01 |
| 2  | 2018-02-02 |
| 3  | 2018-02-03 |
```

What I want to achieve is to update the date (1 day +)  for each column by using mysql event on every 24 hours. So for example

```
2018-02-01 -> 2018-02-02
2018-02-02 -> 2018-02-03
2018-02-03 -> 2018-02-04

etc
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the event scheduler is disabled. In this case you need to enable it by

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler=ON
```

Now you can create an event which updates your table once per day:

```
CREATE EVENT your_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
UPDATE your_table SET date_added=DATE_ADD(date_added, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

To make sure that entries from the same day will not be updated, you can also add a where clause at the end of your create event statement.